# Parse block data from a text file and map it to an entity

Tags: c#, parsing, asp.net-core

I have a text file that has deities data like this:

```
AA
Origin: Egypt
According to the Book Of The Dead, herald at the door of the Third Arit

AABIT
Origin: Egypt
A goddess of song, voice, music and art
```

I wish to parse this data and map it to a Deity entity that has the following properties:

```
public class Deity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The aim is to move the data from a `.txt` to a relational database of some sort using EF Core.

When I open the file in Notepad++ and show line endings, I see this:

[image]

I haven't written parsers before, and I've seen a lot of examples that deal with parsing a text file line by line, but I'm not sure how that would work with this, because mine is sort of block by block instead of line by line.

Is there a way to parse block by block in a .NET Core console application?

Comment: What is `AABIT` ? doesn't look like an `int Id` can you explain the format a little more

Comment: That would be the `Name` of the deity. Sorry, the Ids would be auto-generated by the database engine, assuming I can do the parsing and mapping.

Comment: is there always a blank line to depict a new record?

Comment: yep there will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you could try this.

Assumes there is more than one line of description, and there is a blank line for record end. also that the file as you depicted

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
   while (!sr.EndOfStream)
   {
      var diety = new Deity();
      diety.Name = sr.ReadLine();
      diety.Origin = sr.ReadLine().Replace("Origin: ", string.Empty);

      string val;
      while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val = sr.ReadLine()))
         diety.Description += val;

      deities.Add(diety);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `Id` will get auto generated, while inserted in the db.

Here are the logical steps to parse:

```
var deities = new List<Deity>();
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Your file.txt");
for(int i; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    var line = lines[i];

    // Get the chunk of lines which represents a deity
    var objectLines = new List<string>();
    while(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // check if there is some other character for the blank line, use it here if needed
    {
        objectLines.Add(line);
        line = lines[++i];
        continue;
    }

    // Create the deity object using that chunk
    var deity = new Deity 
    {
        Name = objectLines[0],
        Origin = objectLines[1], // You might have to remove the prefix Origin :
        Description  = objectLines[2],
    };
    deities.Add(deity);
}
```

This isn't tested but should get you the list of deities.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the text file using [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx). Use the empty line and the number of expected lines per entry as indicator that we have to parse the next deity.

This code assumes that each deity uses exactly three lines (i.e. no line breaks inside the Description). It will skip over any empty lines at the start of the file, inside an entry, between entries and at the end of the file.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public static IEnumerable<Deity> Parse(string filePath) {

    var deities = new List<Deity>();
    var currentDeity = new Deity();
    var currentFieldIndex = 0;

    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filePath)) {

        // empty line might indicate next deity
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) {
            // next deity only if all fields of current deity have been found yet
            if (currentFieldIndex > 2) {
                deities.Add(currentDeity);
                currentDeity = new Deity();
                currentFieldIndex = 0;
            }
            continue;
        }

        // at this point we know that the line is not empty
        switch(currentFieldIndex) {
            case 0: currentDeity.Name = line; currentFieldIndex++; break;
            case 1: currentDeity.Origin = line.Replace("Origin: ", string.Empty); currentFieldIndex++; break;
            case 2: currentDeity.Description = line; currentFieldIndex++; break;
            default: throw new ArgumentException("Expected 3 lines per entry.");
        }
    }

    return deities;
}
```

[C# Fiddle for this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O06cc8).